# Ignoring case sensitvity in dplyr joins

Tags: r, left-join, inner-join, dplyr

Is there a way to ignore case sensitvity when doing joins using dplyr?  left, inner, and full?

I see it works with select but this often a huge pain for me.  I know I can convert the columns toupper or tolower before hand, but this would be a helpful work around.

Comment: Can we have a example please. Is this what you meant? https://gist.github.com/jimhester/a060323a05b40c6ada34

Comment: Maybe check the fuzzyjoin package?  It is a variation on dplyr joins and some of the functions there seem related to this.

Answer (score 15):

I don't think there's a straightforward way to get around using `tolower` or `toupper` to tidy the data first. That said, an inline `mutate` (inside the join) would leave the original data untouched if that is preferred.

```
X %>% left_join(Y %>% mutate(id = tolower(id)), by = "id")
```

It works, but we might as well have created a tidy Y with ids to match X in the first place (in my opinion).

Comment: rather than mess with mutating individual columns, I'd probably do something like `...%>% setNames(., tolower(names(.))) %>% ...` to get them all

Answer (score 11):

`dplyr` does not have such an option yet, but with `fuzzyjoin` you can do this very easily:

```
require(fuzzyjoin)
regex_inner_join(x,y,by="id", ignore_case =TRUE)
```

if you have different column names in x and y:

```
regex_inner_join(x,y,by=c("xid"="yid"), ignore_case =TRUE)
```

Comment: There's two right parentheses and one left one in the first join.